# Zabbix frontend ignoring Database config

Tags: mysql, php, zabbix

I had a successful zabbix 3.4 server running in an LXC container (CentOS7 base) with an embedded database for month, and I decided to join all container databases on my server into one.
So I have dumped the zabbix database, moved it to the container, made its 3306 port available.
From the Zabbix container, I can successfully log into the mysql using the command-line. The server backend seems to be able to after updating `/etc/my.cnf`

Problem is the frontend still tries to contact the mysql through a local socket :

```
Error connecting to database: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have tried to rename `/usr/share/zabbix/conf/zabbix.conf.php.example` to `/usr/share/zabbix/conf/zabbix.conf.php` and put database configuration in it but it doesn't change anything. I have tried to grep through the whole `/usr/share/zabbix` directory for my database credentials without success.

Where are stored the frontend database configurations ? Or am I doing anything wrong ?

### Configurations :

```
# grep ^DB /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf 
DBHost=mysql.host #local host name
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=*******
DBPort=3306

# cat zabbix.conf.php 
<?php
// Zabbix GUI configuration file.
global $DB;
$DB['TYPE']                             = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']                   = 'mysql.host';
$DB['PORT']                             = '3306';
$DB['DATABASE']                 = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']                             = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = '******';
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `/etc/zabbix/zabbix.conf.php`, `/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php` or a similarly located/named file? In general, check the `/etc/zabbix/` directory, as your packages seem to prefer it for configuration files.

Comment: well found ! it was there indeed.
I'll try to find a way to notify  Zabbix team to add this to their documentation (as they package the RPMs themselves)

Comment: I was sure it is documented somewhere, but indeed could not find it in the package section of the manual. Please do report it as a bug against the documentation.

Comment: BR : https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-12188